# How to use Custom Image for UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I made a half circle using **CAShaperLayer** and **UIBezierPath**?

like below

```
clockWiseLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];

CGFloat startAngle = -M_PI_2;
CGFloat endAngle = M_PI + M_PI_2;

CGFloat width = CGRectGetWidth(imageView.frame)/2.0f;
CGFloat height = CGRectGetHeight(imageView.frame)/2.0f;
CGPoint centerPoint = CGPointMake(width, height);

float radius = CGRectGetWidth(imageView.frame)/2+7;

clockWiseLayer.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:centerPoint
                                                    radius:radius
                                                startAngle:startAngle
                                                  endAngle:endAngle
                                                 clockwise:YES].CGPath;

clockWiseLayer.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
clockWiseLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
clockWiseLayer.borderColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
clockWiseLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;

clockWiseLayer.strokeStart = 0.0f;
clockWiseLayer.strokeEnd = 0.5f;

clockWiseLayer.lineWidth = 2.0f;
clockWiseLayer.borderWidth = 5.0f;

clockWiseLayer.shouldRasterize = NO;
[imageView.layer addSublayer:clockWiseLayer];
```

Here, stroke color is showing **bluecolor**, How can I put custom shade of color from start to end, or like in start it must be more blue, than as it goes back, it becomes less blue or whitish.

In other approach, I can use **UIImage** instead of it. How can I put a UIImage on this stokeColor.

Thanks.

Comment: do you have a quick example picture of what you mean, as in like this: http://imgur.com/LUwunAR

Comment: if it's something like that, I think I have the solution for you, and it's actual live working code this time

Comment: Let me show you image dear.

Comment: http://imgur.com/92DCTpv like these circle around the globe.

Comment: ahh yeah, okay, let me see what I can do

Comment: Thanks, I'm also trying to sort it out @Larcerax

Comment: sorry, got stuck doing some other crap, will be back to you in like a few hours or less

Comment: I would be thankful, you can give idea, or structure, if you have in mind. I will try to follow that and implement. @Larcerax

Comment: almost done, hold on

Comment: check it out, it works

Comment: use the degress to radians macro i just defined in the answer, it now just goes 1/2 the distance on the right side starting from the top, I also adding a rounded line cap to the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working solution:

it goes all the way around the circle, but you get the idea, its a gradient stroke looking thing:

start with a macro:

```
#define   DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(degrees)  ((M_PI * degrees)/ 180)


UIImageView * shff = [UIImageView new];
    [shff setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_IMAGE"]];
    [shff setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [shff setClipsToBounds:true];
    [shff.layer setCornerRadius:SCREEN_HEIGHT/6];
    [shff setFrame:CGRectMake(SCREEN_HEIGHT/3/2, 100, SCREEN_HEIGHT/3, SCREEN_HEIGHT/3)];
    [self.view addSubview:shff];

    int radius = shff.frame.size.width/2+7;

    CAShapeLayer *arc = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    arc.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(shff.center.x, shff.center.y) radius:radius startAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(-90) endAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(90) clockwise:YES].CGPath;


    arc.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    arc.strokeColor = [UIColor purpleColor].CGColor;
    arc.lineWidth = 15;
    CABasicAnimation *drawAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
    drawAnimation.duration            = 45.0;
    drawAnimation.repeatCount         = 1.0;
    drawAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    drawAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
    drawAnimation.toValue   = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f];
    drawAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];
    [arc addAnimation:drawAnimation forKey:@"drawCircleAnimation"];

    CAGradientLayer *gradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradientLayer.frame = self.view.frame;
    gradientLayer.colors = @[(__bridge id)[UIColor redColor].CGColor,(__bridge id)[UIColor blueColor].CGColor ];
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPointMake(0,0.5);
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPointMake(1,0.5);

    [self.view.layer addSublayer:gradientLayer];

    gradientLayer.mask = arc;
```

screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I just changed my answer so now it works, just use the degrees to radians macro. Also, I just added a rounded line cap to the solution, and changed the starting and ending animation % frames. This should now work without a hitch.

I made a differnet solution, just for Sh%ts and giggles. Here's the newer solution that uses an emitter layer:

```
-(void)doGradientoutline {
    UIImageView * imageView = [UIImageView new];
    [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"df"]];
    [imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(SCREEN_WIDTH/2-imageView.image.size.width*3/2, SCREEN_HEIGHT/4, imageView.image.size.height*3, imageView.image.size.height*3)];
    [imageView setClipsToBounds:true];
    [imageView.layer setCornerRadius:imageView.frame.size.width/2];
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];

    int radius = imageView.frame.size.width/2+7;

    CAShapeLayer *arc = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    arc.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(imageView.center.x, imageView.center.y) radius:radius startAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(0) endAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(360) clockwise:YES].CGPath;

    arc.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    arc.strokeColor = [UIColor purpleColor].CGColor;
    arc.lineWidth = 15;
    [arc setLineCap:@"round"];

    CAEmitterLayer * _myEmitter = [CAEmitterLayer layer];

    _myEmitter.emitterPosition = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, self.view.frame.size.height/2);
    _myEmitter.emitterSize = CGSizeMake(1.0,1);
    _myEmitter.emitterMode = kCAEmitterLayerPoints;
    _myEmitter.emitterShape = kCAEmitterLayerSphere;
    _myEmitter.renderMode = kCAEmitterLayerOldestFirst;
    _myEmitter.shadowOpacity = 0.0;
    _myEmitter.shadowRadius = 0.0;
    _myEmitter.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-10.0,-10);
    _myEmitter.shadowColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:1.00 green:1.00 blue:0.99 alpha:1.0] CGColor];

    CAEmitterCell * _myCell = [CAEmitterCell emitterCell];
    _myCell = [CAEmitterCell emitterCell];
    _myCell.name = @"_myCell";
    _myCell.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime();
    _myCell.birthRate = 80;
    _myCell.lifetime = 8.0;
    _myCell.color = [[UIColor colorWithRed:0.1000 green:0.00 blue:0.5000 alpha:1.00] CGColor];
    _myCell.redSpeed = 1.10;
    _myCell.blueSpeed = 1.10;
    _myCell.alphaSpeed = 0;
    _myCell.redRange = 0.0;
    _myCell.blueRange = 0.0;
    _myCell.alphaRange = 0.0;
    _myCell.contents = (id)[[UIImage imageNamed:@"ffd.png"] CGImage];
    _myCell.emissionRange = 0.00;
    _myCell.emissionLatitude = 0.00;
    _myCell.emissionLongitude = 0.00;
    _myCell.velocity = 0.00;
    _myCell.velocityRange = 0.00;
    _myCell.spin = 2*M_PI;
    _myCell.spinRange = 2*M_PI;
    _myCell.scale = 1.5/ [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
    _myCell.scaleSpeed = 0.00;
    _myCell.scaleRange = 0.0;
    _myEmitter.emitterCells = [NSArray arrayWithObject:_myCell];

    CAKeyframeAnimation *particleAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"emitterPosition"];
    [particleAnimation setPath:arc.path];
    [particleAnimation setDuration:8.0];
    [particleAnimation setRepeatCount:HUGE_VAL];
    [particleAnimation setCalculationMode:kCAAnimationPaced];
    [_myEmitter addAnimation:particleAnimation forKey:@"yourAnimation"];

    CABasicAnimation *drawAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
    drawAnimation.duration            = 1.50;
    drawAnimation.repeatCount         = 1.0;
    drawAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    drawAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
    drawAnimation.toValue   = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.f];
    drawAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];

    [self.view.layer addSublayer:_myEmitter];
}
```

You'll have to download this image and store it in your bundle to make this work, this is NOT a standard image, it uses a few layers of outglow using Adobe Illustrator, this is part of the reason why the emitter glows and changes color, just click the purple fuzzy image below and you'll have you right click and save then import into you project. Call the method above in your viewDidAppear for seemless viewing of how it works, Good luck:

[image]

the new results:

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is not drawCircleAnimation, but it is only half strokeColor. your code is drawing whole circle with that image.

Comment: If you see image, I want lines which are around the globe. I made them using CAShaperLayer and UIBezierPath.

Comment: I know, I told you that, you just have to drop the angle down on the end angle, that's all

Comment: Okay. I will check that later. Thanks by the way. If I get successful. I will let you know :)

Comment: Not appropriate, but appreciating. I don't want tail to touch it, you can say it will cover 270 degrees and continuously move around. like a loading indicator. @Larcerax

Comment: yep, don't worry about the second example, the first example will go to whatever degress you want, just change the degrees_to_radians stuff

Comment: Let me check dear @Larcerax

Comment: You jsut have to animate the view more, that's all, but if you want it to circle around, then thats a different story

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87732/discussion-between-ios-developer-and-larcerax).

Comment: I think you misunderstood my words. I left a chat message for you, check these.

Comment: I wanted these red line to be a custom image.         gradientLayer.colors = @[(__bridge id)[UIColor redColor].CGColor,(__bridge id)[UIColor blueColor].CGColor ];


This line of your code is red, I want here my own image, which I showed earlier in comments of Question.

Comment: uicolor colorwithpatterniamge, that's how